# Qt Creator clang code model doesn't show all warnings

Tags: windows-10, qt-creator

After swtiching to Windows 10, clang code model stopped showing some warnings. I am using default configuration (`-Wall -Wextra`), project has `CONFIG += c++11` in the .pro file.

For example, it doesn't warn about this case:

```
swtich (some_var)
{
case VALUE_1:
     do_something();
     do_something_else();

// doesn't warn about -Wimplicit-fallthrough !!
case VALUE_2:
     do_something_else_entirely();
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has nothing to do with Qt Creator or the OS. For some reason the combination '-Wall -Wextra' doesn't imply '-Wimplicit-fallthrough' on clang.

So the solution is to explicitly include all necessary warnings in the command line string.